# Convert input element to JSON and send to REST service

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm trying to convert a HTML input element and the text within to a JSON object and then send it to a REST service.

How do I go about doing this using vanilla JS, not JQuery or any other libs. I have no clue what to put inside http.send() to send the text inside the input field.

HTML

```
<input id="answer" name="message" type="text" onclick="sendAnswer()" />
```

JS

```
function sendAnswer() {
    http.open("POST", nextUrl, true);
    http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

    http.send(??);
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4033310/3841898

**dublicated**

Comment: @ahankendi - Except that question is about a GET request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're sending a post request, you put the JSON data for your request body inside the https.send()

something like:

```
var data = JSON.stringify({"email":"email@email.com","name":"Bob"});
http.send(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function postRequest(theUrl)
{
          var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();   // new HttpRequest instance 
          xmlhttp.open("POST", "enter your url");
          xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
          xmlhttp.send(JSON.stringify({name:"example name", surname:"data"}));
       return xmlHttp.responseText;
}
```